# Is there any way to pass object as a parameter in laravel livewire?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of product and i am trying to pass a single item as a parameter for quick view, but I can't. anyone have any sollution? thanks in advance.

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
            @php
                $product = (object) $product;
            @endphp
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
                    <div class="product-item product-item-border custom-product-item">
                        <a class="product-item-thumb" href="shop-single-product.html">
                            @if (count($product->related_images) > 0)
                                <img src="{{ $product->related_images[0]['image'] }}" width="233" height="245" alt="Image-HasTech">
                            @endif
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-item-action">
                            <button type="button" class="product-action-btn action-btn-wishlist" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#action-WishlistModal">
                                <i class="icon-heart"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="product-action-btn action-btn-compare" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#action-CompareModal">
                                <i class="icon-shuffle"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" wire:click="quickView({{ $product }})" class="product-action-btn action-btn-quick-view">
                                <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-bottom">
                            <div class="product-item-info text-center pb-6">
                                <h5 class="product-item-title mb-2"><a href="shop-single-product.html">{{ $product->product_name }}</a></h5>
                                {{-- <div class="product-item-price mb-0">{{ $product->default_price }}<span class="price-old">{{ $product->default_price }}</span></div> --}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <div class="ms-4 product-item-price mb-4">{{ $product->default_price }}</div>
                                <button type="button" wire:click="addToCart({!! $product->id !!})" class="info-btn-cart me-4 mb-4"><i class="icon-handbag"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach

            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div wire:click="nextPage" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load more</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and in my controller I am trying to do something like this:

```
public function quickView($product)
    {
        $this->view_product = $product;
    }
```

I tried to pass the object but I am getting error such:
`htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: can you share how you declare "view_product" ? did you use public string $view_product? if yes, change it to public $view_product and try it again

Comment: I did it like this: 
public $view_product;

Comment: i think your error originated from  ... wire:click="quickView({{ $product }})"  ... why do you need to do "$product = (object) $product" inside your livewire blade component ? can you not return list of model Product from your component ?

Comment: I dont need list, i need the specific item from the list to show it on the quick view modal

Comment: so if it's an item, why do you convert it to an object? is it an array of objects?

Comment: yes, its an array of objects

Comment: Is your variable `$this->view_product` declared as an array?(livewire) instead of `$this->view_product = $product`,  use `array_push($this->view_product,$product) `

Comment: and `$this->view_product = []`

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because in blade `{{ }}` will automatically escape the output. And this function only escapes strings.

Instead what you can do is

```
 wire:click="quickView( {{ $product->id }} )
```

And within your livewire component

```
public function quickView($product_id)
{
    // I assume $products is collection
    $this->view_product = $this->products->where('id', $product_id)->first();
}
```

EDIT:
If you do not want to add "extra query" inside quickView()
I suggest you change how $products collection is collected

```
$this->products = $existing_query->get()->keyBy('id');
```

This will resulting array list of object product.

After that within quickView() do the following

```
public function quickView($product_id)
{
    $this->view_product = $this->products[$product_id];
}
```

Extra note: please do add some kind of check or validation in case product with selected id is not found

Comment: That can be a solution, but I want to show the data without query

Comment: you do not do any more sql query, because you already have $this->products, it is just getting a product from existing collection

Comment: i have edited by answer by adding another solution where you do need to add ->keyBy(id) into $this->products query

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little too late but I got to solve something similar by type hinting the object class. From the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#action-parameters)

So maybe you can do something like this:

```
public function quickView(Product $product)
{
    $this->view_product = $product;
}
```